# Upgrading Windows Vista to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

My laptop was built with Windows Vista.

Can I update it to Windows 7? Should I expect a more responsive system? I previously asked about updating my system with Windows XP and was told it wasn't a good idea.

Comment: When did you buy it. Since you might be legible for free upgrade. Check your laptop manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is heads and tails above vista, as this [link shows](http://www.hardcoreware.net/windows-7-vs-vista-performance-comparison/)

I used these [instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd446674(WS.10).aspx) and it worked a treat, good luck

Answer (score 1):

You could run the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displaylang=en). This will tell you if you have enough disk space, any hardware with driver issues etc.

I would expect it to give a Vista capable laptop a clean bill of health, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely expect a more responsive system.

Windows 7 is a *lot* better performance-wise (and in every other aspect IMHO) than Vista.

Though a clean install always results in a more stable system, the folks at Microsoft worked hard to make upgrading painless and, I think, it works like a charm indeed.

Be sure to [check if your system is compatible](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displaylang=en) first.

Comment: Benchmarks, and my own testing, have shown Win7 isn't actually **any** faster than Vista, just the shell is snappier.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if your current computer configuration will be compatible with Windows 7, check out the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to windows 7, you won't regret it.

The best way to describe it is that it "pokes you in the eye less". Technically you should run the [upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx) to find out how easy or hard the process will be, but don't forget to back up everything first.

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded two computers from Vista to Windows 7.  One was a desktop system and the other a laptop.  Both went very smoothly.  The laptop seems to have benefited from a performance improvement with Win7 while the desktop has not noticably improved.